# Accessing arcpy functions from IronPython

Tags: python, arcpy, .net, arcgis-desktop

I made a few python scripts to automatically optimize and publish my data..
Now i'm thinking about writing a .NET program to manage and run these scripts: the obvious way is invoking them in a different process from the .NET code but this seems downright ugly
I was thinking about using IronPython and migrate my scripts into .NET.
Does anyone know if it's possible to invoke arcpy functions from IronPython?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the **[Esri Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/21405-Arcpy-in-SharpDevelop-4.0)** I found a 2011 response from @JasonScheirer which says:

> Arcpy is built on arcgisscripting, which is in turn a CPython
>   extension. You will not be able to use arcpy in IronPython.

Answer (score 1):

An update to this question, this can now be accomplished. You can follow this guide to complete your task in IronPython. [Using ArcPy with Visual Studio 2010 and 2012](http://gisengineering.blogspot.com/2013/06/using-arcpy-with-visual-studio-2010-and.html)